# Python exponent operator and complex numbers

Tags: python, complex-numbers, exponent

Why does python does `print(type(-1**0.5))` return `float` instead of `complex`?

Getting the square root of negative integer of float always mathematically consider as complex numbers. How does python exponent operator support to get `complex` number?

```
print(type(-1**0.5))
 <type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the mathematical order of operations, exponentation comes before multiplication and unary minus counts as multiplication (by -1).  So your expression is the same as `-(1**0.5)`, which doesn't involve any imaginary numbers.

If you do `(-1)**0.5` you'll get an error in Python 2 because the answer isn't a real number.  If you want a complex answer, you need to use a complex input by doing `(-1+0j)**0.5`.  (In Python 3, `(-1)**0.5` will return a complex result.)

Answer (score 2):

Try `(-1)**0.5` instead.

`-1**0.5` is parsed as `-(1**0.5)`, which is equal to `-1`.

```
>>> -1**0.5
-1
>>> (-1)**0.5
(6.123e-17+1j)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exponentiation is being carried out first, and then its sign is inverted. To get the result you want, use parentheses to ensure that the `-` sign stays with the `1`:

```
>>> -1**0.5
-1.0
>>> (-1)**0.5
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
```

Comment: it should return `(0+1j)`, from where did `6.123233995736766e-17` come?

Comment: @PreetkaranSingh - IEEE-standard floating-point math is inexact. Note that 6e-17 is extremely close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Python is correct as `-1**0.5` is different from `(-1)**0.5`.

The first one raises *one* to the power of `0.5` and negates the result.

The second one raises `-1` to the same power and returns a complex number as expected.