# Cube root in python different in shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, python-3.7

I noticed that when I run this program:

```
from random import *
z=random()*-1
print(z)
print(z**(1/3))
```

It returns a complex value. For example, one time its output was

```
-0.08310434620988971
(0.21819489400101133+0.37792464236185713j)
```

However, if I run the equivalent command in the shell, it returns the correct answer:
[image]

I have repeated this experiment several times, with the same result.
Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python exponent operator and complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054794/python-exponent-operator-and-complex-numbers)

Comment: I think an aspect which isn't covered by [Python exponent operator and complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054794/python-exponent-operator-and-complex-numbers) is that Python's exponent operator is returning the so-called principal root. Remember that there are n nth roots. What's returned by z**(1/n) is the root which has the least argument (i.e, least angle wrt the positive real axis), even if there is another root which is real (such as -0.436... in the example above). If you want to get the real root of z**(1/n) with n odd, you'll have to say -((-z)**(1/3)) or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponentiation has a higher precedence to sign. While `-0.08310434620988971**(1/3)` is actually

```
-(0.08310434620988971**(1/3))
```

`z**(1/3)` calculates

```
(-0.08310434620988971)**(1/3)
```

In the second example `z` is already a negative number, so the result in that context is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell you need to wrap your negative number.  due to the order of precedents.

Essentially what the shell thinks your doing is

take the result of 0.08310434620988971 ** (1/3) then prefix it with a negative. since `**` has a higher precedence than `-`. You dont need to do that when its assigned in `z` since thats a single term.

you should get the same result in the shell if you do

```py
(-0.08310434620988971)**(1/3)
(0.21819489400101133+0.37792464236185713j)
```

You can see an easy example of this with a squaring example. All square numbers will be positive.

```py
-2**2
-4

(-2)**2
4
```

without wrapping the negative 2 your saying 2 to the power of 2 which is 4 then apply the negative sign to the result giving -4